# Issue with horizontal and vertical videos inside masonry element

Tags: html, css

I have a masonry element that fills itself with all posts from a facebook page. Some posts are videos, some vertical, some horizontal. My problem: the horizontal videos are shown nicely, you can see the play button and click on it, but the vertical videos are not their full height.

The play button is out of reach and the entire video is in the same parent div size as the horizontal one.

How can I fix that?

I tried giving it a class and setting its width and height to 100% but this is not working.

```
.iframefb iframe{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[You can view the element here.](https://studionewmedia.nl/)

The second post is a video like you can see (10-12-2017) but the post from 01-12-2017 is also a video. How can I make sure no matter what size the video, it just shows as 100% height?

Comment: i guess you should remove `position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 379px;` and make it based on float.

Comment: @sandyJoshi That code is added by my masonry JS. I can't edit that directly.

Comment: then you have to edit style of iframe using java script because you can not modify iframes style from parent frame using css.